# How to recolor all cells based on the original color of the cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I'm looking to recolor cells in a Sheets document I have, simply based on the original color that the cell already has. This is regardless of the contents of the cell and doesn't follow a traditional pattern such as alternating or by simple blocks of color. Is there any way to simply make it work like for example, change all cells currently colored green to the color red? Some of the cells are empty but I'm trying to basically change the colors without having to select every block of cells individually.

Comment: Isn't the original color given by conditional formatting? (by pure chance)

Comment: If your data is in a table format, you can sort your entries by color, which would make it easier to select all your data, and recolor manually.